# Is there a way to avoid deadlock due to shared lock promotions in a same table?

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks

I have an InnoDB table 'test' and there are two transactions querying this table.

Session 1:

```
start transaction;
select * from test where testid = 200 lock in share mode;
```

Session 2:

```
start transaction;
select * from test where testid = 200 lock in share mode;
```

Session 1:

```
select * from test where testid = 200 for update;
-- Trying to get X lock and waits as session 2 already has a shared lock for this entry
```

Session 2:

```
select * from test where testid = 200 for update;
--Deadlock occurs because of Shared lock of session 1
```

Is there a way to get rid of this situation?

Comment: Shared locks are mostly used to ensure consistency (to implement foreign key like behavior). Since the question is about the general case, the only answer here is "you can't". If you can share your specific case, we might be able to provide a solution.

Comment: There is a child table - test_result referring testid in test. When I insert a record in the child table, to ensure the consistency, it acquires Shared lock in test. Later when I update the parent table (it tries acquiring X lock), if there are two concurrent queries fired in this flow, Deadlock occurs.
For now, I have changed the order of queries execution. Insertion taking place after updating after updating parent table.

Comment: If you always update the table, you should use a mutex lock (`FOR UPDATE`). Updating first also does that, and it will work correctly.